# reject creation if attribute has different association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a validation that essentially checks for products added to a cart. If a product has been added, I want to make sure that all the products come from the same store. If it doesn't then adding a product to the cart should be rejected.

I have a `Cart` that has many `line_items`. In a `line_item` there can be several products. Each product belongs to a `store`.

I have quite a complex method for adding items to the cart.

```
def add_product(product_id, instruction, attributes)
  values = attributes.values
  collect_ids = values.map { |attribute| attribute[:product_attribute_id] }.compact
  remove_empty_ids = collect_ids.reject(&:empty?)
  attribute_values = remove_empty_ids.map(&:to_i)

  similar_items = line_items.where(product_id: product_id)
  # adds to cart if product doesn't exist in cart
  if similar_items.empty?
    current_item = line_items.create(product_id: product_id, instruction: instruction)
    attribute_values.each do |attribute|
      current_item.line_item_attributes.create(product_attribute_id: attribute)
    end
  else
    line_item_id = get_line_item_id(similar_items, attribute_values)
    # looks for products to see if all attributes matches
    if line_item_id
      current_item = line_items.find(line_item_id)
      current_item.quantity += 1
      current_item.save
      # if none is found, then create new line item
    else
      current_item = line_items.create(product_id: product_id, instruction: instruction)
      attribute_values.each do |attribute|
        current_item.line_item_attributes.create(product_attribute_id: attribute)
      end
    end
  end
  current_item
end
```

now what I'd like to do is essentially reject the creation if similar items is present, and the `product.store` doesn't match what's already in the DB.

Comment: You should use scopes to create the association to check against then use them in your validations.  That said your code could use more than just the scopes.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Each product belongs to a store, right? So, why not just compare the store_ids on the products in the cart with the new product's store_id? Something like `cart.products.pluck(:store_id).uniq.includes?(new_product.store_id)`